# What colors to choose for colorblind people?

Tags: game-design, accessibility

I'm creating a game. Color coding is its main gameplay feature. What colors should I choose so the game will be colorblind-friendly? (I need 4 colors)

Comment: Interesting continuation, but slightly off topic: https://youtu.be/evQsOFQju08

Comment: You may want to expound on your game's mechanics and goal some.  If player attention and perception is critical to your gameplay, then greater details could be given in the answers that could help craft a richer experience.  I wouldn't know, but perhaps something like the position, shading, combination, area coverage, and movement of colors int he player's view could be carefully controlled as well.

Comment: One thing to consider: There are a number of different types of colorblindness, and you'll have a lot of trouble finding one set of colors that work for everyone. What some games will do is offer several different sets of colors, each of which cater to a different type of colorblindness, so players can choose what works best for them. In cases where color is really important, some games will give the option to overlay a symbol to help players who have total colorblindness (which is rare, but does exist), or who still have problems for all of the color sets offered.

Comment: It might be worth considering adding a Custom Color option if your are only worried about 4 main colors. If done right, then you should be able to create 2-3 sets of default colors (normal, alternate, colorblind, etc), or just have them pick custom colors. It certainly would be the most efficient code wise, though it would take some time programming wise, but you would then never have to worry about colorblindness of any kind.

Comment: Look into 508 compliance.

Comment: See also [How can I find an optimum set of colors for 10 players?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/46463/how-can-i-find-an-optimum-set-of-colors-for-10-players), and [What's a good alternative to colored tiles to account for color blindness?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/55658/whats-a-good-alternative-to-colored-tiles-to-account-for-color-blindness).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are different kinds of color blindness which occur in different intensities.

The most frequent ones are red-green blindness and yellow-blue blindness (each indicating which two colors affected people can **not** tell apart).

Here are different forms of color blindness and how frequently they occur in the general population. Source of these numbers is [the Wikipedia article on color blindness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_blindness#Types):

```
              men    women
red-green       9%     0.5%
blue-yellow   < 1%    <1%
all colors    (negligible)
```

As you can see, red-green blindness is by far the most common form of color blindness. However, it predominately affects men. For women, it is even less frequent than the next most frequent kind: blue-yellow blindness. So keep your target demographic in mind when you prioritize different kinds of color blindness.

The most flexible way to take care of any form of color-blindness is simply to make the colors used by your game configurable in the options menu. That way every player can set a color combination which works for them.

Or you can use this palette from the article [*Color Universal Design (CUD) How to make figures and presentations that are friendly to Colorblind people*](http://jfly.iam.u-tokyo.ac.jp/color/) by Masataka Okabe and Kei Ito.

[image: colorblind-save palette]

By the way: You might want to skim the whole article. While it focuses on scientific presentations in front of an audience, it also has plenty of advise which is transferable to game design.

Here's a copy paste friendly version of the above picture:

C,M,Y,K (%)

```
(0,0,0,100)
(0.50,100,0)
(80,0.0,0)
(97,0,75,0)
(10,5,90,0)
(100,50,0,0)
(0,80,100,0)
(10,70,0,0)
```

R,G,B (0-255)

```
(0,0,0)
(230,159,0)
(86,180,233)
(0,158,115)
(240,228,66)
(0,114,178)
(213,94,0)
(204,121,167)
```

R,G,B (%)

```
(0,0,0)
(90,60,0)
(35,70,90)
(0.60,50)
(95,90,25)
(0,45,70)
(80,40,0)
(80.60,70)
```

Hex codes

```
#000000
#E69F00
#56B4E9
#009E73
#F0E442
#0072B2
#D55E00
#CC79A7
```

Comment: Isn't 0.5% also less than 1%?

Comment: @SGR ask wikipedia.

Comment: A good alternate solution is to add glyphs or texture which match the colors, eg horizontal stripes, vertical stripes, diagonal stripes and polka dot for each color. If this interferes with your vision of the game you can make this a separate option.

Comment: +1 for the table and enabling configuring all colors. Exactly what I would have answered as well.

Comment: A compromise if you can't come up with pretty colors that work for all blindnesses, is to offer different color sets where you just swap out one of the problematic colors. That way, you can have a design that looks pretty for most people, but instead of adding yet another setting, and a color picker control, and whatever else, you can get away with one "colors" popup with, say, 4 choices: "recommended", "avoid red-green", "avoid yellow-blue" and "grays". Also saves time on QAing everything for *any* color combo.

Answer (score 5):

I'm mainly red/green color blind. The colors I always choose when given a choice in situations like this, are:

- Red
- Blue
- Yellow
- Grey

Those I can always tell apart.

Color combinations I have problems with are mainly the following:

- Red/green
- Red/brown
- Green/brown
- Yellow/orange
- Red/orange
- Pink/grey
- Sky-blue/light grey
- Purple/dark blue

Hope it helps :-)

Answer (score 3):

*The following is informed by my experience as someone with slight red/green colorblindness - specifically protanomaly.*

When choosing colors, think about differentiating colors by **brightness** in addition to just **hue**.

A naive approach in choosing colors is to say "Okay, I need four colors. Let's go with primaries: red, green, blue and yellow. So that's #FF0000, #00FF00, #0000FF, and #FFFF00. Done!"

The problem with this approach is that all your colors are sitting at maximum brightness. Someone who has difficulty with red/green colorblindness might not be able to tell the difference between maximally bright yellow (red+green) and maximally bright green (or red).

Instead, in addition to spacing the colors out by hue, you should also space them by *brightness*. For example, don't have *bright* green and *bright* yellow, but have a *dark* green versus a *bright* yellow, to help out those people who may have red/green colorblindness. Even if they can't distinguish the hue of the color, they can tell that the colors are different by their brightness.

This isn't a foolproof method, of course. There's a wide range of colorblindness types, and certain types are less about not being able to distinguish between different colors and more about not having the same sensitivity to particular wavelengths, so the perceived brightness for a colorblind person will be different than for a non-colorblind person. (This is what happens with my protanomaly. I'm less sensitive to red light than the average person, so reds are darker for me than for others: really dark red is easily confused with black, and I can pick up the green much better than the reds in fully saturated computer yellow, so it's easily confused with fully saturated computer green, as are dark blues with dark purples. - Though I can still pick up large differences in brightness.)

Adding a "colorblind mode" where something else besides color (e.g. shapes) is used to distinguish things is also a good idea. But keep in mind that there's a range of severity in colorblindness, and many "colorblind" people can still perceive colors. So your "colorblind mode" should *add* extra distinguishing factors, rather than *replacing* the color. (I've seen games which turn everything black & white in "colorblind mode".) Ideally you should be able to have your "colorblind" features on all the time.

But one thing you definitely want to do is to extensively play test you game with things "de-hued". Either through some colorblindness simulator (but remember the multiple types), or simply by converting everything to greyscale. I've experienced a few games whose "colorblind mode" was obviously an afterthought. For example, one game just added numeric labels to the colored balls. The problem with this was that the game was time-sensitive and distinguishing between a 2 and a 3 is harder (takes a fraction of a second longer) than distinguishing between colors. So levels that were comfortable for normal sighted persons using colors were unplayable to someone relying on the labels.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I need to pick a set of colours, I use [colorbrewer](http://colorbrewer2.org/). Even though it is technically for maps, you can it for everything, and they let you choose between different pallets based on your preferences (like colour blindness).

Answer (score 1):

There are different types of colorblindness, so you may not be able to be friendly with all of them, but the two major types are red-green and blue-yellow colorblindness.

This means that these people have trouble differenciating red from green or yellow from blue. So for your game, try avoiding **red** AND **green** at the same time (same goes for yellow and blue).

Answer (score 1):

To add to the other answers, you can use a colorblindness simulator such as [Color Oracle](http://colororacle.org/) to detect problems with your color scheme.

Also, while this may not be applicable to your game, Jon Blow of [The Witness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Witness_(2016_video_game)) made sure that puzzles which depended on discerning different colors were optional.